# Magento: How can i edit related product title?

Tags: php, magento

It's magento 1.9.2 can you guide which block/file i can edit to change title/label of related products?

http://prntscr.com/dte49k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **Magento template path hints** to find the related file.

Log into the magento back-end admin

Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu

Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

you can find more details in [link](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)

also if you have SSh , you can search the word "related products" using command **fgrep -r "related products"**